# Ajax update table with php content

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax, json

How to make an animated table only animate when a new record is added to the database.

Ajax/Js (in index.php):

```
$.ajax({
url : 'Not sure what goes here?',
data : {Not sure what goes here?},
dataType : 'application/json', // Is this correct?
success: function(response) {
    // Only when successful animate the content
    newItem(response);
} 
});

var newitem = function(response){
var item = $('<div>')
    .addClass('item')
    .css('display','none')
    .text(response)
    .prependTo('#scroller')
    .slideDown();
$('#scroller .item:last').animate({height:'0px'},function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
}
```

My php (latest.php):

```
include ('db.php');
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `feed` ORDER BY `timez` DESC";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){

$user = $row3['username1'];
$action = $row3['action'];
$user2 = $row3['username2'];

echo ''.$user.''.$action.''.$user2.'<br>'; // Needs to be a json array?
```

I can't get this to work, here's how the table operates http://jsfiddle.net/8ND53/ Thanks.

Comment: What in your code isn't working, what are you having problems with?

Comment: I don't know how to arrange it I'm not good at ajax it wont grab any data from the latest.php page.

Comment: I want to pass what "echo ''.$user.''.$action.''.$user2.'<br>';" returns. For example: user1 liked User2  User4 disliked User1  I want the table to show the latest user activity.

Comment: what data you want to pass to php? After URL write the location of the php code

Comment: have you checked jquery.com/ajax ? there are so many examples answering your really basic question.

Comment: If you want to use the data when you call back to jQuery then yes you need json. use the following format for json within the while loop: $arrVaraiable[] = array('var 1' => $row['username1'], 'var 2' => $row[action]); Outside the wile loop you need to use the following: echo json_encode($arrVariable); You also need to set the data_type to json inside jquery :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
 url : your_php_file.php',
 data : {data you'r going to send to server}, // example: data: {input:yourdata}
 success: function(response) {
     $('#table_id').append('<tr>'+response+'</tr>'); // response is the date you just inserted into db    
 } 
});
```

in `your_php_file.php`:

```
add the item into db
echo that inserted data # if you echo, then you can catch this with ajax success function then you append it into your table.
```

Comment: Wont this just put all the data in one <tr></td> I need it in separate lines showing only the latest 5 records.

Comment: @user1933466, then you need to loop till 5 and in every loop do that append

Answer (score 1):

try to fill as below:

```
$.ajax({
type: "post"
url : 'locationOfphpCode/phpCode.php',
data : {data you want to pass}, //{name: "dan"}
success: function(response) {
    // Only when successful animate the content
    newItem(response);
} 
});
```

in your php code you need to receive the data you have passed from the ajax call:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
...
?>
```

you may add some validations in your php code.

hope this will help you.

Comment: What is "name:" where does it come from I don't have any identifiers called "name"...

Comment: it is just an example, it can be anything you will pass with `data` option of the `$.ajax` function

Comment: Does the ajax go in my index.php with the table or in the php page that grabs the content from sql? And is "name:" calling on "$name" or "['name']"?

Comment: if I understand you correctly the ajax call "goes" the the location you giving it in the url option.

Answer (score 0):

the example you have given is using `setInterval(newitem, 2000)`

so you have to call ajax function on some fixed interval.

Comment: No I want it to update when new record is added to the database. Not at an interval that was just an example on how the table moves.

Comment: Ajax function will call on some interval but you can make condition for response if new record in database then you can send responce to javascript otherwise send nothing to javascript